# How do you shift the starting index of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to switch the starting index of an array of ints in C. To be precise I have the following array:

```
{ int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};}
```

I wish to change {array} to an array of 3 items containing {2,3,4}. I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this using pointers and without shifting all the elements in the array. I am also happy if {array} remains an array of 4 items as long as the first 3 items are {2,3,4}. I tried the following:

```
{array = &(array[1])}
```

However, this does not work and I get an error saying {incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[4]’ from type ‘int *’}.

I was under the impression that a C array was a reference to the first element of the array.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: That impression is a misconception, which is still erroneously considered "more intuitive" and therefore still taught. It often bites one in the rear sooner or later.

Comment: An array name is a **constant** that describes the entire block of memory allocated for that array.  It can never be assigned to.  When used as a *value* it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element, through which the array elements can be accessed and modified.

Comment: @DaleHagglund: An array name is an expression of array type. It can be implicitly converted to a pointer value *in some contexts*. Expressions of array type are simply not assignable in C, not just array names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a few options:

**Move all elements left by one**

If preservation of the contents are not required:

```
int array[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

then you copy/move the elements from index position n to index position n-1:

For example:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
  array[i-1] = array[i];
```

You can also look into `memmove` which might be more efficient.

For example,

```
memmove(array, array+1, sizeof array - sizeof *array);
```

which does the same thing as the loop above.

**Copy elements into a new array ignoring the first**

If preservation of the original data is required, then you can create another array and copy the elements into that ignoring the first element.

For example,

```
int array1[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int array2[3];
int i;

for (i = 0, i < SIZE_OF_SMALLER_ARRAY; ++i)
  array2[i] = array1[i+1]
```

**Use a pointer to refer to array[1] as array[0]**

If you want to use pointer eliminating the need to move/copy data:

```
int array[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *pArray = &array[1];
```

Now pArray points to the second element in the array effectively allowing you to index array[1] as pArray[0]

**Use an array of int pointers**

```
int array[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *parray[3];

int i;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_SMALLER_ARRAY; ++i)
  parray[i] = &array[i+1];
```

**Caveats**

One thing you can't do is...

```
int array1[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
array1 = &array1[1]; // !! Compiler Error !!
```

The reason is `array1` is a `non-modifiable l-value`. Essentially a constant.

You also can not do this...

```
int array1[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int array2[4] = array[1] // !! Compiler error !!
```

The reason here is you can not initialize an array in this context.

Comment: One thing to note is that given `int array[4]`, you can use `sizeof` to get the size of the array, and therefore the number of elements (`sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`). Most of these solutions (which are perfectly valid) don't give you something you can meaningfully apply `sizeof` to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, `p` points inside the original `array` though. `array` is unchanged.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};
        int *p = array + 1;
        printf("%d %d %d\n", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
        return 0;
}
```

prints "2 3 4"

You can shift an array using `memmove`, but it does move around all the bits.
Arrays can be copied with `memcopy`, again the bits are copied.

As shown above pointers allow you to move around within the array.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'shrink' or 'expand' ie. change size of array created this way in C/C++.

What you might look into is dynamically memory allocation with which you can do things like that.