# reducing array by reassigning it to one of its elements with & operator in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote a simple recursive function for binary search that takes three arguments: an array of integers, the length of the array and a value to find. The idea is that at every recursive call it either halves the length and keeps the array[0] in place or moves the starting index to the middle (third line from the bottom in my sample). That is until the value is found or length is 0.

Then I saw this disccussion: [How do you shift the starting index of an array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711246/how-do-you-shift-the-starting-index-of-an-array-in-c)

It is said here that an array name is a constant and cannot be reassigned in C. So my question is why this code works?

```
int rsearch( int needle, int haystack[], int size ) {

if (size == 0) {
    printf("%i not found\n", needle);
    return 0;
}

int mid = size / 2;

if (haystack[mid] == needle) {
    printf( "found %i in the array\n", needle );
    return 1;

} else if (haystack[mid] > needle) {
    return rsearch( needle, haystack, size / 2 );

} else {
    haystack = &haystack[mid + 1];
    return rsearch( needle, haystack, (size - 1) / 2 );
}
```

I'm just studying, and my knowledge of pointers is very limited. And there's no practical application here. Just curious.

P.S.
The other question is what happens to the memory allocated to the original array when it's reduced this way? Is it made available again or is it a memory leak?

Comment: When an array is passed to a function it degenerates to a pointer and is no longer an array as far as the function is concerned. This is subtle and you may need to read further to understand this. Also function parameters are passed by value in C. So the `haystack` in the function is just a pointer to the start of the original array and is not the array "name" itself.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks a lot. I think I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays when used as function arguments actually mean a pointer to an array, but not the array as value. So the following function signatures are equivalent: `void test(int xptr[10])`, `void test(int xptr[])`, and `void test(int *xptr)`.

At the point where an array is defined, however, you can only initialise it's value, but you cannot assign any other value later on.

When you pass an array, let's say `int x[10]` to a function by just using `x` as parameter, like in `test(x)`, then array `x` automatically decays to a pointer to the first element of `x`.

See the following code showing the difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int xptr[10]) {

    printf("value of xptr[0]: %d\n", xptr[0]); // -> 0

    xptr = &xptr[2];  // OK; xptr will point to element 2

    printf("value of xptr[0]: %d\n", xptr[0]); // -> 2
}

int main(){

    int x[10] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    // x = &x[2];  // Error: Array type 'int [10]' is not assignable

    // but:
    test(x);  // OK; and is eqivalent to...
    test (&x[0]); // OK;

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a function argument, this:

```
int haystack[]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
int *haystack
```

This is mainly because an array decays to a pointer to the first element when passed to a function.

So what you have is not an array but a pointer.  Unlike an array, a pointer is a modifiable lvalue, so it is allowed to assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted
>   to ‘‘qualiﬁed pointer to type’’...

and (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Thus in this function declaration

```
int rsearch( int needle, int haystack[], int size );
```

the parameter `int haystack[]` is adjusted to `int *haystack`. So these function declarations

```
int rsearch( int needle, int haystack[100], int size );
int rsearch( int needle, int haystack[10], int size );
int rsearch( int needle, int haystack[], int size );
int rsearch( int needle, int *haystack, int size );
```

declare the same one function. You may include all these declarations in your program because a function declaration may appear more than one time. However the function shall be defined only one time (if it is not an inline function).

Accordingly the array passed to the function as argument is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

Take into account that it would be better to declare the function like

```
int rsearch( int needle, const int *haystack, int size );
                         ^^^^^
```

In this case the function can be used also with constant arrays.

> It is said here that an array name is a constant and cannot be
>   reassigned in C.

It would be correctly to say that array is not a modifiable lvalue.

From the C Standard (6.5.16 Assignment operators)

> 2 An assignment operator shall have **a modiﬁable lvalue** as its left
>   operand.

and (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 1. ...A modiﬁable lvalue is an lvalue that **does not have array type**,...

Comment: Thank you. This is very exhaustive.